# Finding Location / Coordinates in Dart

Tags: javascript, geolocation, dart, dartium

For a project I am doing I really need to find a location or Coordinates. I do not know how to get a Location / coordinates, I dont think that dartium supports many ways of getting locations / coordinates. I am guessing I would use navigator.getLocation but it is not working. Help?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this bug report (https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15866) it is not supported.
You need to build to JavaScript and run in Chrome to get the location.

When you use `pub serve` (as recent DartEditor versions do) you can open the same URL in Chrome you are using in Dartium.

Comment: I understand, but how would you find the location in the first place, what is the code for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394124
Add a comment if it doesn't work. The question is a bit old. This question/answer seems to indicat that it works in Dartium when you provide the API keys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824595

Comment: When I use that code, I get an error saying that there is not meant to be any arguments, so when I get rid of the arguments and put it to a string it outputs: Instance of '_Future<Geoposition>' Help?

Comment: Can you please add the code you used to your question and point out at which statement you get the error.

Comment: I was using the code from the link that you gave me, and the statement is:   window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((Geoposition position) {
      window.alert(position.coords.latitude.toString());
  });

Comment: I added a second link to this comment, the code there seems to be more current. Please try this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60402/discussion-between-lucaspeedstack-and-gunter-zochbauer).